# Display div content of iframe on top of the screen

Tags: php, iframe, fancybox

I have created a page which have one button. On clicking of the button, it is showing fancybox popup  with `iframe`.

`iframe` has one `inputbox`. While inputting text, it suggests name list like auto-complete option. Due to fixed size of the `iframe` popup, the suggestion list is not visible after fixed height and width. Auto populating suggestions are inherited in `iframe`.

So all of my auto suggested list is not properly visible. It's hidden inside the `iframe`. So I want to pop up outside of `iframe`.

Please help if anybody has solved these types of issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does your fancybox show scroll bars when the iframe `height` increases?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have a control over the iframe , you can give a greater z-index value to the auto-compete list than the iframe fancy box.
2. Or Add style overflow:scroll; for the container which holds the iframe and set the iframe height to max

**Example** :

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="width:400px; height:400px; overflow:scroll">
    <iframe src="http://www.example.com/" style="width:1000; height:1300"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Bala  for your reply,
I have already tried to add overflow:scoll and greater z-index. It adds scroll. But i want auto-complete list div top of iframe without changing height and width.